# Showing that an operator is $w^{*}-w$ continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space.  Fix $x\in \ell_{1}[X]$, the space of all absolutely summable sequences in $X$.

Define an operator $T:X^{*}\to\ell_{1}$, $\varphi\mapsto (\varphi(x_{n}))_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

$\bf{\text{Problem:}}$  Show $T:(X^{*},w^{*})\to (\ell_{1},w)$ is continuous.

---

$\bf{\text{My Attempt:}}$

My argument has a gap in it which may not even work.  But this is the best I could come up with.  Can anyone suggest how to fix my proof? or how to prove it properly?

Suppose $\varphi_{n}\to\varphi$ in the $w^{*}$-topology on $X^{*}$.  Then $\varphi_{n}(y)\to \varphi(y)$ for every $y\in X$.

Now let $\psi\in \ell_{1}^{*}$, and identify $\psi$ with an element $(b_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\in \ell_{\infty}$.

I need to show that $\psi[T(\varphi_{n}) - T(\varphi)]\to 0$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\psi[T(\varphi_{n}) - T(\varphi)]\right| &=& \left|\psi[(\varphi_{n}(x_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty} - (\varphi(x_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}]\right|\\
&=& \left|\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}[\varphi_{n}(x_{k}) - \varphi(x_{k})]\right|\\
&\leq& \|b\|\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\varphi_{n}(x_{k}) - \varphi(x_{k})\right|\\
\end{eqnarray*}$

For each $k\geq 1$, choose $n_{k}\geq 1$ such that for $n\geq n_{k}$, $|\varphi_{n}(x_{k}) - \varphi(x_{k})| < \epsilon 2^{-k}$.

Let $N = \sup_{k\geq 1}n_{k}$.  $\color{red}{(!)}$ I still need to show that this is finite for my argument to work.

Then for all $n\geq N$, the series above is bounded by $\|b\|\epsilon$, and I am done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that one could prove that $\sup_{k\geqslant 1}n_k < \infty$.

But that is not necessary.

You have a linear operator $T$, and you want to show that that is continuous. Since the weak$^\ast$ topology on $X^\ast$ is not metrizable in general (when $\dim X = \infty$), using sequences is not sufficient to prove continuity. You have three options to show continuity,

1. use nets,
2. use filters,
3. use neighbourhoods.

Using neighbourhoods is in my opinion the most natural way.

So you need to show that for every weak neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ in $\ell^1$, the preimage $T^{-1}(V)$ is a weak$^\ast$ neighbourhood of $0$ in $X^\ast$. It is enough to show that for each weak neighbourhood in a subbasis of weak neighbourhoods of $0$. By definition of the weak topology, a subbasis of neighbourhoods of $0$ is given by the family

$$\mathcal{S} = \{ \lambda^{-1}(\mathbb{D}) : \lambda \in (\ell^1)^\ast \},$$

where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk if the scalar field is $\mathbb{C}$, and the interval $(-1,1)$ if the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$.

Identifying $(\ell^1)^\ast$ with $\ell^\infty$ as usual, the archetypical neighbourhood is then

$$V_b = \left\lbrace s \in \ell^1 : \left\lvert \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\cdot s_k\right\rvert < 1\right\rbrace$$

for $b \in \ell^\infty$. We insert the definitions and find

$$T^{-1}(V_b) = \left\lbrace \varphi \in X^\ast : \left\lvert \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\cdot \varphi(x_k)\right\rvert < 1 \right\rbrace.$$

Now we use that $(x_k)$ is an absolutely summable sequence, and $(b_k)$ is bounded. That implies that the sequence $(b_k\cdot x_k)$ is also absolutely summable:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lVert b_k\cdot x_k\rVert = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert b_k\rvert\cdot \lVert x_k\rVert \leqslant \lVert b\rVert_\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lVert x_k\rVert < \infty.$$

And hence, we can define $\xi = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k\cdot x_k$, and see that for $\varphi \in X^\ast$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\varphi(x_k) = \varphi\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\cdot x_k\right) = \varphi(\xi)$$

by linearity and continuity of $\varphi$. Thus

$$T^{-1}(V_b) = \left\lbrace \varphi \in X^\ast : \left\lvert \varphi(\xi)\right\rvert < 1\right\rbrace$$

is an archetypical weak$^\ast$ neighbourhood of $0$ in $X^\ast$, and $T\colon (X^\ast, w^\ast) \to (\ell^1, w)$ is shown to be continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is a great answer.  I completely overlooked the non-metrizability of $X^{*}$